# Load Datatables with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

How do i make my Datatable work with Turbolinks when a user revisits page where the table is located. It works fine the first time you visit the page. however if you move to another page and then come back to it. the page loads what was there previously then quickly all the data in the table dissapears.

I am using the ajax-datatable gem in rails with following code:

in cashflow coffeescript:

$ ->
        $('#cashflows_table').dataTable

```
        processing: true
        serverSide: true
        select: true
        ajax: $('#cashflows_table').data('source')
        url: 'cashflows/index.html.erb'
        type: 'POST'
        pagingType: 'full_numbers'
        columns: [

            { searchable: true,  orderable: true, data: 'date' },
            { searchable: true, orderable: false, data: 'description' },
            { searchable: true, orderable: true, data: 'amount' },
            { searchable: true, visible: false, orderable: true, data: 'created_at' },
            { ssearchable: true, visible: false, orderable: true, data: 'updated_at' },
            { searchable: false, visible: false, orderable: false, data: 'user_id' },
            { searchable: true, visible: true, orderable: true, data: 'name' },
        ]



    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'




   $("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
        alert "The article was deleted."
        ('#cashflow_table').dataTable.fnDestroy
$ ->
    $('#form-show').click ->
        $('#form-section').toggle()

$ ->
    $('#form-hide').click ->
        $('#form-section').slideUp()
        false
```

The cashflows datatable class has the following code:

```
class CashflowDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
  def user
    @user ||= options[:user]
  end
  def view_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    # or in aliased_join_table.column_name format
    @view_columns ||= {
      # id: { source: "User.id", cond: :eq },
      # name: { source: "User.name", cond: :like }

      date: { source: 'Cashflow.date', cond: :like, searchable: true},
      description: { source: 'Cashflow.description', cond: :like },
      amount: { source: 'Cashflow.amount', cond: :eq, searchable: true},
      created_at:{ source: 'Cashflow.created_at', cond: :eq },
      updated_at: { source: 'Cashflow.updated_at', cond: :eq },
      user_id: { source: 'Cashflow.user_id', cond: :eq },
      category: { source: 'Cashflow.category.name',cond: :eq,
                searchable: true },
      name:         { source: 'Category.name', cond: :eq,
                    searchable: true }
    }
  end



  def data

    records.map do |record|

      {

        date: record.date, 
        description: record.description,
        created_at: record.created_at,
        updated_at: record.updated_at, 
        user_id: record.user_id,
        name: record.category.name,
        amount: record.amount,
    }

    end
  end

  private

  def get_raw_records   

    Cashflow.where(user_id: options[:current_user].id).joins(:category)
  end

  # ==== These methods represent the basic operations to perform on records
  # and feel free to override them

   def filter_records(records)
    ->(column) { column.table[column.field].eq(column.search.value.to_i + 1) }
  end

  # def sort_records(records) 
  # end

  # def paginate_records(records)
  # end

  # ==== Insert 'presenter'-like methods below if necessary
end
```

My cashflows table HTML template looks as follows:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class=col-md-12>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class="col-md-12" style = 'background-color: white'>
                <button id= 'form-show' class= 'btn btn-primary form-btn'> Add Transaction</button>

          </div>     

                <div class='row'>
                <br/>
                    <%=render 'form'%>
                </div>

 <br/>


                <table id="cashflows_table" 
                 class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                  width="100%", 
                  data-source = "<%= cashflows_path(format: :json)%>">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-1" scope="col">Date</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" scope="col">Description</th>
                             <th class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" scope="col">Amount</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-1" scope="col">created_at</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-1" scope="col">udpated_at</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-1" scope="col">user_id</th> 
                            <th class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-1" scope="col">name</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="table-hover"> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>



            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my application.html.erb is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta text/html; charset="UTF-8"> 
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
        <title>
            Cash Flosum
        </title>

        <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', "data-turbolinks-track": "reload" %>
        <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', "data-turbolinks-track": "reload"%>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'%>

        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload">

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>


            <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 

            <!--Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
            <script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>


    </head>

    <header>    
        <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
        <%= render 'layouts/messages'%>
    </header>

    <body>

        <div class = 'container-fluid'>
            <%= yield %>

        </div>


    </body>
    <foot>
        <%=render 'layouts/footer'%>
    </foot>
     <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with the `ajax-datatable` gem, but turbolinks has it's [own set of events](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events) that differ slightly from vanilla jQuery. You may want to consider replacing the traditional DOM-ready scripts wrapped with `$ ->` to use the `turbolinks:load` event. So for your snippet, something like:

```
$(turbolinks:load) -> 
  $('#cashflows_table').dataTable
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    select: true,
    ajax: $('#cashflows_table').data('source'),
    url: 'cashflows/index.html.erb'
    type: 'POST'
    pagingType: 'full_numbers'
    ...
```